# New Fields under "MetaData-Tab" after removing Content Field - Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

After removing the Content field from a pagetype, all new fields added to **Root.Main** appear under the MetaData-Tab. That's very annoying. Can someone tell me how to get the new fields above the MetaData-Tab?

Here's my code

```
        $fields->removeFieldsFromTab('Root.Main', array('Content'));

    $newsObjectField = new GridField('News', _t('Dict.NEWS', 'News'), $this->News(), CreateUnsortableGrid::create());
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $newsObjectField);
```

Thx in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addFieldToTab` adds the new field at the end of the list by default.

So you could use something like:

```
$newsObjectField = new GridField('News', _t('Dict.NEWS', 'News'), $this->News(), CreateUnsortableGrid::create());
$fields->fieldByName('Root')->fieldByName('Main')->insertAfter($newsObjectField, 'MenuTitle');
```

`insertInsertBefore` works similarly.

Here `MenuTitle` can be any other field name you want.

`fieldByName` works with the dotted syntax, so it could also be `$fields->fieldByName('Root.Main')`.

**Edit**

pointed out by **@Zauberfisch** `addFieldToTab` can take a third argument that lets you specify which field to insert before:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $newsObjectField, 'Metadata');
```